# Prevent passing of options when defining a new class

Tags: documentclass-writing

I'm defining a new class. In this class I created an option `total`. This however breaks the document since apparently this option is passed to the `geometry` package, even though I'm not specifying this should happen. I thought that options were only passed in case this was explicitly done using `\PassOptionsToPackage` or `\RequirePackageWithOptions`. How can I prevent this from happening? My current work around has been to change the name of the option, but I don't like that. Who knows what will break in the future?

Below is a minimal (non-)working example.

The class definition:

```
% example.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{example}

\DeclareOption{total}{}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{beamer}

\endinput
```

and a file using it:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass[total]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you'd need to remove it from `\@classoptionslist`

Comment: OK, I had a look at how I should do this, and got something working. I will post it as an answer, so people can verify whether it is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove `total` from `\@classoptionslist`; the easiest method is using `expl3`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{nvcleemp}

\DeclareOption{total}{}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_remove_all:Nn \@classoptionslist {total}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\LoadClass{beamer}

\endinput
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment by David Carlisle, I came up with this answer:

```
% example.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{example}

\DeclareOption{total}{}

\def\temp@classoptionslist{}

\DeclareOption*{%
   \xdef\temp@classoptionslist{\temp@classoptionslist,\CurrentOption}%
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\let\@classoptionslist\temp@classoptionslist

\LoadClass{beamer}

\endinput
```

This works for me, but maybe there is some problem I didn't think about.